# Excel One cell to many formula (I realize this may not be possible)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

First of all I want to start by saying I know this is either extremely difficult or impossible.

I have data (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suvarnabhumi_Airport#Passenger), on any airport in the airlines and destinations list), in one column is the airline name, and in the other is a list of destinations seperated by commas and occasionally some extra info.

What I need is to get each destination in a seperate row, with the airline name beside it, and the extra info (Charter, seasonal, "begins....", references) in a third column.

I will be doing this repeatedly with multiple Wikipedia tables. I am creating a route map on Kumu.io . It is ok is any solution doesn't quite do everything, I just need something close as there is no way I will be able to do it all by hand. If you need more info just let me know. Thank you for any assistance, this is truly an awesome resource.

The data is in this format

[image]

And I need it to look like

[image]

Comment: This could be doable, but I don't understand. You have 3 columns (A:Destination, B:Airline, C:Extra info [comma seperated]). Where are you aggregating this extra info from exactly (I don't see it on the Wikipedia page)? Please clarify.

Comment: Also, you can always upload images to sites like photobucket, that would be helpful.

Comment: I agree it probably can be done, but you need to better explain. I'm just as confused as @NateBergeron

Comment: Hey Guys, Firstly thanks for your interest, your help is appreciated. Ok got links for screenshots [Data as copied from wikipedia](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mafqx8cb654qg9b/Capture.PNG) and [data as I want it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6uzcq0hps4ti8m/Capture2.PNG) Now in the example I left out some destinations in the interest of saving time. It isn't particularly important which column it goes to though. The information is copied from the airlines and destinations table in the wikipedia page for any airport, in this case Bangkok.

Comment: Also, the extra info I am referring to is this. In some instances of a destination it will say charter or seasonal, or will simply have a reference link. It isn't on all of them though.

Comment: Do you know how to write a macro?  You would need to know visual basic for applications, VBA for short, in order to write said macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear if you actually have hyper links or not (some are coloured, some are underlined and some not)

I have no idea if this can be done with worksheet functions, but this VBa does it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CrazyAirlines()

'************** There are things you may need to edit here

Dim currentRow As Integer
currentRow = 1 'I assume we start on row 1, if row 1 is actually headings, change this to the first row of data

Dim destinationRow As Integer
destinationRow = 1 ' assuming there is no heading again, if there is, change to a 2

Dim airlineCol As String
airlineCol = "A"

Dim destinationCol As String
destinationCol = "B"

Dim extraCol As String
extraCol = "C"

Dim origSheet As String
origSheet = "Sheet1" ' the name of of the sheet where the values currently live

Dim destSheet As String
destSheet = "Sheet2" ' this is the sheet name where the results will be

' *********** Hopefully you don't need to edit anything under this line!!

Worksheets(destSheet).Cells.Clear

Do While (Worksheets(origSheet).Range(airlineCol & currentRow).Value <> "")

    Dim airline As String
    airline = Worksheets(origSheet).Range(airlineCol & currentRow).Value

    Dim destinations As String
    destinations = Worksheets(origSheet).Range(destinationCol & currentRow).Value

    Dim extraInfo As String

    Dim title As String

    Dim spInfo() As String
    spInfo = Split(destinations, ":")

    If (UBound(spInfo) > 0) Then
        title = spInfo(0)
    End If

    destinations = Replace(destinations, title & ":", "")

    Dim spDest() As String
    spDest = Split(destinations, ",")

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(spDest)

        Worksheets(destSheet).Range(airlineCol & destinationRow).Value = RemoveSquare(Trim(airline))

        Dim des As String
        des = RemoveSquare(spDest(i))

        Dim containsExtra() As String
        containsExtra = Split(spDest(i), "(")

        If UBound(containsExtra) > 0 Then
            title = Replace(containsExtra(1), ")", "")
            des = containsExtra(0)
        End If

        Worksheets(destSheet).Range(destinationCol & destinationRow).Value = Trim(des)

        If (title <> "") Then
            Worksheets(destSheet).Range(extraCol & destinationRow).Value = title
            title = "" 'kill it, kaboom, bang, boom (not good words considering this is about airlines, but hilarious
        End If

        destinationRow = destinationRow + 1

    Next i

    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Loop

End Sub

Function RemoveSquare(s As String)

Dim sp() As String
sp = Split(s, "]")

    If UBound(sp) > 0 Then
        RemoveSquare = sp(1)
    Else
        RemoveSquare = s
    End If

End Function
```

Sheet1 looked like

[image]

And after I ran the above VBa, my Sheet2 looked like

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone, @daverook that is perfect, I can't vote up because I'm new, but I really appreciate it, Thanks again.

Comment: Hey again, I am completely new to VBa, is there anychance you could add to what you have already answered, so that it removes spaces from the start of the cell? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the issue.  Do you mean you are getting results like ' airline' and you want 'airline'

Comment: Yes, thats it exactly, except it is in the destination column (sheet 2 Column B). Thanks again